# Dockerfile Cant Find Successfully Copied Files with RUN

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am attempting to develop a Mozilla SOPS Docker container that uses Age for encryption.
Here are my files:

**./Dockerfile:**

```
FROM alpine:latest

# Install sops
RUN wget https://github.com/mozilla/sops/releases/download/v3.8.1/sops-v3.8.1.linux.amd64 -O /usr/local/bin/sops \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/sops 

# Install age
RUN wget https://github.com/FiloSottile/age/releases/download/v1.1.1/age-v1.1.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz -O /usr/local/bin/age \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/age

RUN export PATH=/usr/local/bin:${PATH}

# Copy the script to generate_sops_config.sh
COPY ./src/generate_sops_config.sh /app/config/generate_sops_config.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/config/generate_sops_config.sh

# Execute the script to generate .sops.yaml and private keys
RUN /app/config/generate_sops_config.sh
RUN chmod 600 /app/config/.sops.yaml

# Cleanup
RUN rm -f /app/config/generate_sops_config.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sops"]
```

**./generate_sops_config.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Generate age key pair
age-keygen -o age_key.dev.txt
age-keygen -o age_key.prod.txt

# Extract the public key
prod_age_pubkey=$(cat age_key.dev.txt.pub)
prod_age_pubkey=$(cat age_key.prod.txt.pub)

# Update .sops.yaml with the public key
cat <<EOF > .sops.yaml
creation_rules:
  - path_regex: \.dev\.yaml$
    age: |
      -----BEGIN AGE ENCRYPTED FILE-----
      ${dev_age_pubkey}
      -----END AGE ENCRYPTED FILE-----

  - path_regex: \.prod\.yaml$
    age: |
      -----BEGIN AGE ENCRYPTED FILE-----
      ${prod_age_pubkey}
      -----END AGE ENCRYPTED FILE-----
EOF
```

**./docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  sops-service:
    build:
        context: .
    volumes:
      - ./shared:/app/shared/
      - ./config:/app/config/
```

This gets to layer 7/9

```
 => [sops-service 6/9] RUN chmod +x /app/config/generate_sops_config.sh                            0.3s
 => ERROR [sops-service 7/9] RUN /app/config/generate_sops_config.sh
```

I run this after first creating the two empty volumes (`./shared` & `./config`) Then running `docker-compose up`.

Any idea whats going wrong here? I have been troubleshooting for about an hour and a half now with no luck getting Docker to see the file during the build process.

Comment: btw. regarding `**#!/bin/bash**` (garbage) vs `#!/bin/bash` (bash script), see <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)>

Comment: and please restore `#!/bin/bash` in your listing; `**#!/bin/bash**` is just meaningless garbage

Comment: Sorry about that. I failed that edit attempt.

Comment: `RUN export PATH=/usr/local/bin:${PATH}` is doing nothing and can be removed. It's like running `a=b` in a terminal and closing the terminal. Any variables set in a temporary shell run on `RUN` are removed when shell exits. You meant to write `ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `generate_sops_config.sh` script begins with a "shebang" line that requires `#!/bin/bash`.  A minimal Alpine-based image doesn't include the GNU bash shell.  However, it also doesn't look like your script is using any bash-specific features; you should be able to use any POSIX shell here.

If you change the "shebang" line to

```bash
#!/bin/sh
#      ^^ (not bash)
```

then the script should run fine.  For more complex scripts, you need to make sure to avoid bash-specific features like array-type variables, and unnecessary syntax like `function` or `source` keywords.

Answer (score 2):

Short: the "not found" does not refer to the file `/app/config/generate_sops_config.sh`, it refers to the interpreter `/bin/bash` mentioned in the file.

- your `generate_sops_config.sh` requires `bash` (therefore it says `#!/bin/bash` in its first line), and the Alpine Linux image comes without `bash` preinstalled (because Alpine wants to be small, and `bash` is big).
- so insert `RUN apk update && apk add bash` before `RUN /app/config/generate_sops_config.sh`; this will install `bash` in your image

(There are more problems later on; maybe you have to do some more `apk add` to satisfy dependencies; but that's another problem.)

PS: Question well written on your part, that was very easy to reproduce!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this was my working result:

**./Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:3.19.0

# Install bash (generate_sops_config.sh dependency) and age
RUN apk update && apk add age

# Install sops
RUN wget https://github.com/mozilla/sops/releases/download/v3.8.1/sops-v3.8.1.linux.amd64 -O /usr/local/bin/sops \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/sops
```

**./src/generate_sops_config**

```
#!/bin/sh

# Generate age key pairs and capture both stdout and stderr
dev_pub_key=$(age-keygen -o /app/config/age_key.dev.txt 2>&1 | sed -n -e 's/^.*Public key: //p')
prod_pub_key=$(age-keygen -o /app/config/age_key.prod.txt 2>&1 | sed -n -e 's/^.*Public key: //p')

# Update .sops.yaml with the public key
cat <<EOF > "/app/config/.sops.yaml"
creation_rules:
  - path_regex: \.dev\.yaml$
    age: ${dev_pub_key}

  - path_regex: \.prod\.yaml$
    age: ${prod_pub_key}
EOF

chmod 600 /app/config/.sops.yaml

# Initial run forever to help debugging
trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait
```

**./docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  sops-service:
    build:
        context: .
    volumes:
      - ./shared:/app/shared/
      - ./config:/app/config/
      - ./src/generate_sops_config.sh:/opt/generate_sops_config.sh
    entrypoint: ["/opt/generate_sops_config.sh", "rm -f /opt/generate_sops_config.sh"]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: and it seems your files got shorter, that's a good sign ;-) less noise to think about!